# how to read and write to Virtual com port in java

Tags: java, virtual-serial-port

I want to read and write to virtual com port that is dynamically created by CP2101 driver when i connect a device through USB To UART Bridge to my system.the problem is that with rxtx we can not find that which com port is assigned to the connected device.only we can manually set the port(say "COM1").in my case virtual port is automatically created so any idea to read that  virtual port will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. You need to know the port to open it, so find the port or ask the user. Same as for a proper serial card, except that's somewhat less likely to change (it's still quite possible)

Comment: but how to find the port that is allocated to device because we can not find in java that which port is assigned to the device by driver only we manually can assigned the port.actually i want  to read the vendor Id or Product Id.I know one solution is using JNI but any other if idea if you have.